# build.gradle is not part of the build defined by settings file

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to build a Gradle file and getting the error `Build file '.../build.gradle' is not part of the build defined by settings file '.../settings.gradle'. If this is an unrelated build, it must have it's own settings file.`

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.4.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-securing-web'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    // tag::security[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    // end::security[]
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}
```

Here is my settings.gradle:

```
/*
 * This settings file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * The settings file is used to specify which projects to include in your build.
 * In a single project build this file can be empty or even removed.
 *
 * Detailed information about configuring a multi-project build in Gradle can be found
 * in the user guide at https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
 */

/*
// To declare projects as part of a multi-project build use the 'include' method
include 'shared'
include 'api'
include 'services:webservice'
*/

rootProject.name = 'gs-securing-web'
```

How do I get this to build?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had same issue. I see there is no answer, though I'm late, this might be helpful for others.

Copy the settings.gradle file from the available location and paste it and needed location.

In my case Error was -

```
* What went wrong:
Project directory '/Users/pradeepbehera/Downloads/ud867-master/1.04-Demo-GroovyClosuresAndObjects' is not part of the build defined by settings file '/Users/pradeepbehera/settings.gradle'. If this is an unrelated build, it must have its own settings file.
```

I copied `settings.gradle` file from `/Users/pradeepbehera/settings.gradle` and pasted at `/Users/pradeepbehera/Downloads/ud867-master/1.04-Demo-GroovyClosuresAndObjects`.

Then it worked just fine.

Comment: So others know, I found all I needed was a settings file with a "rootProject.name" set (I had many more options for the main project).

Comment: I dont think this is the right thing to do all the time. Instead, we should run the gradle command from the top level and provide appropriate rule.

Comment: Don't do this, the correct answer is by [matthew_automater](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61354216/10969548)

Answer (score 60):

I was running into the exact same issue:

org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: **Project directory** 'Users/Shared/myProject/theDirectory/src/test **is not part of the build defined by settings file** 'Users/Shared/myProject/theDirectory/settings.gradle.

The issue was I was running gradle from a terminal window that was based too far down in the directory structure.

**The FIX:**  simply Change Directories in the terminal window `cd ..`

So for me I simply backed up to directory levels to: "myProject" folder and boom...simple gradle works.

Comment: This answer seems to be on the right path, but how can I tell Android Studio where it should run the command from ? Because if I open the project from my /android/ subfolder it will detect gradle fine, but then it's unable to access the /.env file... and also I can't work on the cross-platform code located in the root folder as the project only opens in the /android/ scope

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Genius! This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered the same problem recently which actually brought me to this question.

In my case, I was trying to build the jar from the wrong path '../project/someFolder' and I corrected my path to '../project'.

Answer (score 2):

In my case my project did not have a settings.gradle file, so I went ahead & created an empty one as per this [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#always_define_a_settings_file):

> Always add a settings.gradle to the root directory of your build to
> avoid the initial performance impact. This recommendation applies to
> single project builds as well as multi-project builds. **The file can**
> **either be empty or define the desired name of the project.**

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time this happens when you are using `Deprecated Gradle features were used in your build.gradle, making it incompatible with the latest Gradle version your IDE` refers.

**Found the right fix for a similar issue** after I lost almost half a day to figure out a fix for this issue in IntelliJ in Ubuntu OS.

*Finally found myself the solution by chance:*

Just by setting Gradle version pointed to locally installed version, and Gradle JVM chose the installed version of JDK in your local machine, this solved my problem
[image]

Comment: ... and that window no longer exist (or at least not the bottom part). Great, that seemed like it would fix my current problem, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Run your gradle / gradlew command on the project where you can see settings.gradle

example:
gradlew dependencies

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to delete that file from the root path. The file wasn't inside my project and that was strange.